# Catching shouldHave/shouldBe method in Selenide

Tags: java, selenium, selenide

I'm writing a test and there's a possibility to not load all fields correctly. I was thinking about using simple try/catch, but when I use

`$("select[formcontrolname=\"idenifier\"]").shouldBe(disabled);`

I get:

```
Element should be disabled {input[type="text"]}
Element: '<input class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 with-tooltip ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" formcontrolname="identifier" placeholder="e.g. "America" type="text"></input>'
Actual value: enabled
```

Which is not a standard exception. How can I catch it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch an AssertionError thrown from any of Selenide's assertions.

You probably shouldn't though, usually when your assertion is not being met by a certain timeout, you either have a bug or an incorrect assertion.

Comment: Great idea! Following code worked perfectly:
            `try {`
                `$("select[formcontrolname=\"idenifier\"]").shouldBe(visible);`
          `} catch (AssertionError e) {`
                `throw new Error("A new error was thrown!");`
            `}`

Answer (score 0):

If this is a dropdown and a disabled one , then it should have an attribute 'disabled'  added in the DOM.

```
<select class='xxxx'>
    <option disabled='disabled'>
```

if you have this then you can easily verify the element being disabled.

If not you can first go for a check for if it's displayed or not and then go for another check on being disabled.

```
$("select[formcontrolname=\"idenifier\"]").shouldBe(Condition.visible).isEnabled();
```

This should return you if the drop down is enabled or not.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about if I have this field disabled by a bug and I want to catch it, without throwing an error and interrupting tests?

Comment: If there's no disabled field or it has been marked as a bug, in that case you'll have to write the above mentioned code inside a try catch block and have to specify in catch that which type of Exception you are expecting.
And inside catch block you can specify some other actions to be performed in the browser as part of clean up.